# General Java API for password mutate / hash / digest

Tags: java, api, passwords, salt, digest

My web application is secured with [salted, digested passwords](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/secure-password-storage-donts-dos-and.html) using [container managed authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbe.html#bncbj).  I'd like to reduce the coupling with my current container by having a [service in JNDI](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Adding_Custom_Resource_Factories) that handles the password mutation / verification.  I was after something like this:

```
/**
 * A service for mutating passwords with salt.
 * Note that the same password should yield different mutations every time.
 */
public interface PasswordMutationService {
    /**
     * Mutates the given password for storage purposes.
     * The 'salt' must be coded into the result so that it can be extracted later.
     */
    String mutatePassword(String password);

    /**
     * Confirm the given password was used to create the given stored mutation.
     *
     * @param candidatePassword     The password supplied by a user that wants to be authenticated.
     * @param storedMutatedPassword A mutation of the users password retrieved from storage.
     */
    boolean verifyMutatedPassword(String candidatePassword, String storedMutatedPassword);
}
```

Do you know of an API that supplies this interface so I don't have to write and manage my own?  I have a hard time believing it's not in Java EE somewhere.

NOTE: I'm not after a Tomcat Realm, that has [already been done](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/support-for-salted-passwords-tp5011904p5012069.html).  Nor do I need the implementation, that [is done too](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/freshcode_public/learn/tomcat-maven-plugin/tomcat-salted-passwords/src/main/java/pkg).

Comment: Won't you still be tied to your container? I'm confused by how implementing your own abstraction helps you here.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Elliott, my application needs the 'mutatePassword()' feature to save / mod user info.  The corresponding container adapter needs 'verifyMutatedPassword()' feature.  If I move to another container then only a new container adapter needs to be written; I don't even have to recompile the app.

Comment: Jim, I hear what you're saying about subjectively correct answers.  My question is for anyone that has come across this type of interface before because I can't find it and it seems pretty generic.  I'll try to tweak the question to be more useful and will await community verdict on whether to close it.

Answer (score 0):

To decouple my application from the password digest implementation I really only need one method:

```
String mutatePassword(String password)
```

The container plugin can be coupled to the digest implementation without too much harm so it does not need 'verifyMutatedPassword()' to be on an interface.

After browsing some JDK7 API's I found [something that could do the job](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Provider.html) (if you're not easily offended):

```
public interface Provider<T> {
  public T invoke(T request);
}
```

This means my application can tap into [password mutation](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/freshcode_public/learn/tomcat-maven-plugin/tomcat-salted-passwords/src/main/java/pkg/PasswordMutator.java) with:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
passwordMutator = (Provider<String>) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/bean/appPasswordMutator");
```

The tomcat container config for password mutation and security realm is:

```
<Resource name="bean/appPasswordMutator" auth="Container"
          factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
          type="pkg.PasswordMutator"
          seedNumBytes="8"
          keyNumBits="160"
          digestIterationCount="10000"
          singleton="true"/>

<Realm className="pkg.PasswordMutationRealm" 
       userCredCol="usercred"
       passwordMutatorName="bean/appPasswordMutator" 
       localPasswordMutator="true"
       localDataSource="true"
       dataSourceName="jdbc/appDb"
       userTable="usercred"
       userNameCol="username"
       userRoleTable="userrole"
       roleNameCol="userrole"/>
```

A working demo is available from my SVN repo at:
https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/freshcode_public/learn/tomcat-maven-plugin
(See READ_ME.txt file)